# JoGL not drawing within a loop

Tags: java, opengl, for-loop, drawing, jogl

I have working on an OBJ model loader in JoGL for a few days, and can obtain the vertices in the array draw: `draw[face][vertex][x,y,z,or w]` I have tried several ways to render this array (i.e. VBO's) but none have worked so far. I decided to attempt to render the face within a loop, however, when I run the program nothing is rendered. Here is my code:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++){
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            //start drawing
            for(int i2=0;i2<draw[i].length;i2++){
                float[] xyzw = new float[4];
                //grab all the vertex values
                for(int i3=0; i3<draw[i][i2].length;i3++){
                    xyzw[i3]=draw[i][i2][i3];
                }
                gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    // Set the current drawing color to red
                gl.glVertex3f(xyzw[0], xyzw[1], xyzw[2]);
            }
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

The peculiar thing is if I do this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++){
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            //start drawing
            for(int i2=0;i2<draw[i].length;i2++){
                float[] xyzw = new float[4];
                //grab all the vertex values
                for(int i3=0; i3<draw[i][i2].length;i3++){
                    xyzw[i3]=draw[i][i2][i3];
                }
                gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    // Set the current drawing color to red
                gl.glVertex3f(xyzw[0], xyzw[1], xyzw[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   // Top
                gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    // Set the current drawing color to green
                gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left
                gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    // Set the current drawing color to blue
                gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Right 
            }
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

then I get a contorted shape, however without those extraneous vertices nothing is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Luckily (or unluckily) the points are correct. I am choosing this method (actually) to check if my loading method works. I appreciate the comments and will attempt to re-factor this into a class. However, I cannot see how this will fix this problem.

Comment: Given the second test rules out many other issue, the first thing I'd try is changing GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP to GL_LINE_STRIP or even GL_POINTS, just to make sure there are no degenerate vertices that would otherwise cause solid geometry not to be rendered. The OBJ format provides polygons, not triangle strips too.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize the OBJ file format did not provide triangle strips; so if I triangulate the polygon into a triangle strip, the drawing should work.

Comment: creating an efficient triangle strip from an arbitrary mesh can be quite complicated. traingulating is much easier (a simple way is to create a triangle fan using the first point as the centre). just for testing purposes you could use GL_POLYGON, but ideally a VBO with GL_TRIANGLES is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the :

```
float[] xyzw = new float[4];
```

this array should be in the out of the loop, because this array by every iteration initial and filled.
for solving your problem must create this array in out of the loop:

```
float[][] xyzw = new float[x][4];
```

x is the number of your vertexes,